# Exclude current sticky post

Tags: query-posts, sticky-post

I have the following query, trying to fetch the latest sticky posts but exclude the current one:

```
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
rsort( $sticky );
$sticky = array_slice($sticky, 0, 3);

query_posts(
    array(
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'post__in' => $sticky,
        'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    )
);
```

Getting the posts works fine, but `post__not_in` doesn't. Is there an effective way to do this?

Comment: Read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters). _Note: you cannot combine `post__in` and `post__not_in` in the same query._

Comment: And [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
// Get sticky posts
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
rsort($sticky);
$sticky = array_slice($sticky, 0, 3);

// Check if current post is inside
foreach ($sticky as $key => $value)
    if ($value === $GLOBALS['post']->ID) {
        // ... and remove
        unset($sticky[$key]);
        break;
    }

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post__in' => $sticky,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    )
);
```

---

If you want to have 3 posts (no matter what), you have to do it like so (minimally changed):

```
// Get sticky posts
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
rsort($sticky);

// Check if current post is inside
foreach ($sticky as $key => $value)
    if ($value === $GLOBALS['post']->ID) {
        // ... and remove
        unset($sticky[$key]);
        break;
    }

$sticky = array_slice($sticky, 0, 3);

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post__in' => $sticky,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    )
);
```

**// EDIT**: added `break` after current post ID has been found and removed, in case you have a great number of sticky posts.

Comment: Works like charm :D Thanks alot for the effort and patience